# PDO fetch returns empty first row

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to store data from PDO query into an array as follows.

```
$array[] = array();
$query = "SELECT m.fac_id, m.tnc_id FROM `CCF` m
        INNER JOIN `CCF-1` f ON f.fac_id = m.fac_id
        WHERE f.form_id = :id";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array('id' => $ccf_id));

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($obj = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $array[] = [$obj['tnc_id'], $obj['fac_id']];
    }
    return $array;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

There are two issues:

1) if the table is empty, using `$stmt->fetch()` without checking first if `$stmt->rowCount() > 0` returns an empty array element, i.e. `[[]]`, when what I need is `[]` or an empty array.

2) hence I added an if statement `$stmt->rowCount() > 0` so that an empty table will return `[]`, which worked. However, now non-empty tables will have a first value that is empty, i.e. `[[],[1,2],[3,4]...]`, which messes up the later part of my code.

How do I ensure that the output is either `[]` or `[[1,2],[3,4]...]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$array[] = array();
```

to

```
$array = array();
```

The `[]` after `$array` means that `$array` will be an array and the first ever index to exist (created via `[]`) will be an `array()`.